# Disable timestamp update in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Faced the problem: when i am trying to update field via `active record` in `CodeIgniter` there also updates `timestamp` field. For example my code:

```
$this->db->where('user_i', 1);
$this->db->update('ci_users', $user_info);
```

Creates this sql:

```
UPDATE `ci_users` SET `user_fullname` = 'asdasdfsafd' WHERE `user_iD` =  1
```

But after execution there also changes `ci_users.user_creation_date` field. Where there may be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what `timestamp` fields are for.
If you don't want them to be altered on update - use `DATETIME` instead

Answer (score 1):

Mysql will automatically update the timestamp to current-timestamp if you have give default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or NULL to the column, so the solution is that you should not give the default value to that column...